# Load Firebase Vision OCR with white list dictionary of words to recognize

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am using Google Firebase Vision API for Text Recognition (OCR). My use case is to do OCR on a persons name in a document or at the head of a document. Furthermore, I have a database or list of names that I expect to be scanning. I know that other OCR engines support loading the engine with a list or dictionary of words which helps improve recognition. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with Firebase Vision Text Recognition. If I have a list or array of names, can I load those in the engine as the only strings/words to recognize?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ML Kit does not support custom text dictionary for now. But I could raise this in our internal discussion.

One alternative solution for now is to filter the detected text with your dictionary, so that non-interested texts are ignored.